# ASP.NET MVC form without helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I would like to create a form in my asp.net MVC website, without using HTML helpers like @Html.EditorFor()...

I also want to use Jquery Mobile.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-iconpos="right">
        <legend>Languages :</legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-6a" id="checkbox-h-6a">
        <label for="checkbox-h-6a"></label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-6b" id="checkbox-h-6b">
        <label for="checkbox-h-6b">French</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-h-6c" id="checkbox-h-6c">
        <label for="checkbox-h-6c">German</label>
</fieldset>
}
```

I would like to use it with my model. (for ex. "bool UseEnglish", "bool UseFrench",..)

How can I do it simply ?

Comment: If you don't want to use any of the helpers then you can just not use them.  You'll just have to put in your form tags and markup.

Comment: Sorry if the question was stupid. But I still want to use my Model and the data validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing the helpers really do is abstract the `name` attributes of the form fields away. If you don't want to use the helpers, you will just have to make sure the `name` attributes are set to the right thing so that they will match up to your model after POST.

For simple properties, the name is just the property name, so given:

```
public string Foo { get; set; }
```

You'd have an input like:

```
<input type="text" name="Foo">
```

For things like complex types or reference navigation properties, you'll just chain the property names together until you're at the level you need, so given:

```
public Foo Foo { get; set; }
```

And:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

You'll end up with:

```
<input type="text" name="Foo.Bar">
```

Finally, for list-style properties, you'll just add an index, so given:

```
public List<string> Foos { get; set; }
```

Then:

```
<input type="text" name="Foos[0]">
<input type="text" name="Foos[1]">
<input type="text" name="Foos[2]">
```

And of course, you can put all of these principles together to model any relationship:

```
public List<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
```

Then:

```
<input type="text" name="Foos[0].Bar">
```